# Quarkus native image tests and injection

Tags: integration-testing, quarkus

Quarkus doesn't allow injecting objects into a native image test (I do not understand why, but that's a separate topic). How am I supposed to write a test then, that relies on injected objects? In my case the non-native test gets a JPA `EntityManager` injected which is created by Quarkus based on the application configuration. I use the entity manager to create test data and query expected results in the database afterwards. How should this work with a native image test? Creating the entity manager manually isn't really a solution because there is also Flyway involved and other steps that Quarkus - fortunately - usually does automatically.

Comment: Did you find any suitable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use any injection as you already pointed out, you have to rely on simpler libraries to write the test data to your DB.

Instead of using an injected `EntityManager`, you can use a plain `java.sql.Statement` to execute the insert query using JDBC, or you can use a library like MyBatis. You can place this insertion code in a `@BeforeEach` annotated method in your test class.

You will be still able to inject the connection properties to use for the test data inserts (e.g. URL, DB password) via `@ConfigProperty` annotated fields within the test class.